# How I view every contents in jquery dialog using php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-dialog

I am creating a table using php and this is how it create table body.

```
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {      
    // Create Table Body
    $html .= "<tr>\n";
    $html .= "  <td>$title</td>\n";
    $html .= "  <td>$date</td>";                            
    $html .= "  <td align='center'>\n";
    $html .= "      <a href='#'>\n";
    $html .= "          <span class='view' title='View This Comment'></span>\n";
    $html .= "      </a>\n";
    $html .= "  </td>\n";                           
    $html .= "  <td class='td_catchall' align='center'>\n";
    $html .= "      <a href='#'>\n";
    $html .= "          <span class='edit' title='Edit This Comment'></span>\n";
    $html .= "      </a>\n";
    $html .= "  </td>\n";                       
    $html .= "  <td align='center'>\n";
    $html .= "      <a href='#'>\n";
    $html .= "          <span class='delete' title='Delete This Comment'></span>\n";
    $html .= "      </a>\n";
    $html .= "  </td>\n";
    $html .= "</tr>\n"; 
}
```

Using this table there are 3 columns to view, edit and delete each comments. I want to trigger a jquery dialog for each action. I tried to get it to work with view dialog. But it is display only one comment for each link. I added code to view dialog in while loop like this -

```
//Create View Blog Dialog Box 
$viewBlog  = "<div id='dialog-view'>\n";
$viewBlog .= "      <h2>$title</h2>\n";
$viewBlog .= "  <p>$date</p>\n";
$viewBlog .= "  <p>";
$viewBlog .= "          <img src='".UPLOAD_DIR.$userName."/".$image."' />";
$viewBlog .= "      $comment</p>";
$viewBlog .= "</div>\n";
```

**UPDATE**

My jQuery -

```
$( "#dialog-view" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 450,
        width: 650,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }, 
        position: { 
            my: "center top", 
            at: "center top",
            of: "#content"
        }
}); 

$( ".view" ).click(function() {
    $( "#dialog-view" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

Can anybody help to figure this out. 
Thank you.

Comment: I think first and foremost what did you try with the jquery to make it work, as you specified. seeing as your creating a dialog, that loads these elements in to the DOM post render, chances are you will need to use something like `.on()` instead of `.click()` but it also depends on your jQuery version as well. Show us your javascript (jquery) for what you tried with the `click` event.

Comment: @chris Check my question. I updated it.

Comment: @TNK: As an aside consider using a template for that instead of saving the HTML in a PHP var.

Comment: @diosney Can you kindly elaborate your comments? If possible with an example. Thank you.

Comment: @TNK: **Sure!** You can have a separated `.php` file which have sort of marks `(<?php echo $var_name; ?>)` at the places you want to susbtitute and then `include` this file inside the `while` statement. Be aware of before `include`ing the file you have to fill the vars used there. If you want we can move to the chat to explain this to you better. This  way you have the logic separated from the user interface :D

Comment: @diosney yes, can we chat about this? If not can you show me an example how to do this.. Thank you.

Comment: @TNK: Go to http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php and shout me, I will be there :)

Comment: @TNK: Just write: "@diosney" and write something.

Comment: @diosney When you have time please let me know.. I want to learn how to logic make separate from presentation layer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the code for dialog inside a while loop, it would have created multiple dialog. But all of them with same id `dialog-view`. So always the first occurrence loads.

You can achieve opening specific dialog by appending a variable `eg: $i` as follows

```
//Create View Blog Dialog Box 
$viewBlog  = "<div id='dialog-view-$i'>\n";
```

Then in the first while loop,

```
<span class='view' onclick='$(\"#dialog-view-$i\").dialog(\"open\");' title='View This Comment'></span>\n";
```